# Getting unique and unused items from a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a (MySQL) database table that contains the history of parts that the company leases or sells.  The table might contain data such as:

Table: inventory

```
id|type|serial
--------------
 1|recv| 1234
 2|recv| 2345
 3|recv| 3456
 4|leas| 2345
 5|sold| 1234
 6|ret | 2345
```

In the above example, we received (stocked) three items in inventory with serial numbers 1234, 2345, 3456.  Item 2345 was leased and then returned, while item 1234 was sold.  What I need is the ability to see what items are currently available for lease or sale.

In this example I should have 2345 and 3456 returned from a SQL query since 3456 was never touched and 2345 was leased, but returned (placing it back in inventory).  I'm not sure if I need to use 'DISTINCT' in my SQL query or what.

**Update:** sorry, I was misinformed about the database layout.  Here's the actual setup:

Table: inventory_history

```
id|date|action
--------------
 1|....| recv
 2|....| leas
 3|....| sold
 4|....| ret
```

Table: inventory_serials

```
id|fk|serial
--------------
 1| 1| 1234
 2| 1| 2345
 3| 1| 3456
 4| 2| 2345
 5| 3| 1234
 6| 4| 2345
```

The tables where setup so that there could be one listing of the history (e.g. received/stocked) with multiple serial numbers being assigned to that one instance.  So in this example, items 1234, 2345, 3456 are associated to the received/stocked history (row 1 in inventory_history).  Item 2345 (inventory_serials) is related to row 2 (inventory_history), etc.

Comment: Have you tried using `Select "somevalue" where "condition"`

Comment: The database needs to be restructured, dumping this into a single table is a mistake

Comment: Thanks for the reply DoctorDerp. Currently I haven't even come up with a sql query yet as I wouldn't even know how to accomplish what I'm attempting.  What would an example query look like that accomplishes my stated goals?

Comment: In what way should this be redesigned user574632?

Comment: @user574632 well, not really. Imagine that the serial is the foreign key to the "Product" table. It then makes perfect sense. I should only add a date to the inventory table but maybe it does exist in the actual schema....

Comment: Actually there is a relationship between multiple tables in the DB.  I'm updating the post to reflect this - sorry everyone.

Comment: I'm sure you can think of a better name than `fk` in your second table `;-)`. How about `inventory_history_id`?

Comment: @halfer thanks, thats not the actual name of the column. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following query selects the latest `id` for each item and then checks if that `id` record has `recv` or `leas` or `ret` type, indicating the item's availability.

```
SELECT
inventory.*
FROM inventory
INNER JOIN
(SELECT serial, max(id) id
FROM inventory
GROUP BY serial) max_id
ON inventory.id = max_id.id
WHERE type in ('recv', 'leas', 'ret');
```

**EDIT**:

Based on the revised table structure, the following query can be used:

```
SELECT
iss.*
FROM inventory_serials iss
INNER JOIN
(SELECT serial, max(id) id
FROM inventory_serials
GROUP BY serial) max_id
ON iss.id = max_id.id
INNER JOIN inventory_history ih
ON iss.fk = ih.id
WHERE ih.action in ('recv', 'leas', 'ret');
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb06e2/4).

Comment: Joseph can you please update your post based on the updated information?

Comment: @user1646428 Please see modified query above.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick!  Thanks Joseph!  +1 for quick resolution!